# How does return >=> f work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

In particular, my question is about how this is considered to be equivalent to f itself?

We know that type of `return` is:: `a -> m a` and the type of `>=>` is:: `(a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)` So when we apply `>=>` to `return` and f, won't there be a type mismatch, because won't we have `(a -> m a) -> (b -> m c)` as the types of `return` and f respectively, which means how can we even apply `>=>` now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's rename some type variables to avoid confusion:

```
return :: a -> m a
(>=>)  :: (b -> m c) -> (c -> m d) -> (b -> m d)
```

When we apply `(>=>) return`, we need to make

```
(a -> m a) = (b -> m c)
```

(type of `return` and type of `>=>`'s first argument).

Therefore we have

```
a = b
a = c
```

(and thus `b = c`, too).

Then

```
(>=>) return :: (c -> m d) -> (b -> m d)
a = b
a = c
```

which is

```
(>=>) return :: (a -> m d) -> (a -> m d)
```

So as long as `f :: a -> m d`, we can apply `(>=>) return` to `f` and get a value of the same type back.